# How do I write video/image to saved photos album using PHPhotoLibrary?

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary

Hi all I'm using ALAssetsLibrary to write videos/images to the album. 
But XCode is telling me that ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated and I need to use PHPhotoLibrary, which is all well and good but there are no examples or documentation of how to make this transition.

Can anyone show me how to change this code to use PHPHotoLibrary?

```
let data:NSData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
let image:UIImage = UIImage( data: data)!

let library:ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
let orientation: ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: image.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
library.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image.CGImage, orientation: orientation, completionBlock: nil)
```

and for video:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary().writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL, completionBlock: {
        (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)

        }

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(outputFileURL)
        } catch _ {
        }

        if backgroundRecordId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundRecordId)
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving image:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
}, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
    // completion callback
})
```

Video:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: mediaUrl as URL)
}, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
    // completion callback
})
```